# How to access an RDLC variable from C#

Tags: c#, variables, reporting-services, rdlc

In a C# RDLC file, I have set up a report variable called `test`.

I have a table and based on the value in the row. I want to set the report variable.

Below is a field from the table. I check to see if the first letter is `H`, and set the variable to `1`, otherwise, it displays a value `2`.

```
=iif(Left(Fields!StockSymbol.Value,1)="H",Variables!test.Value = 1, "2")
```

So what happens is that `test` is not equal to `1`, so the grid prints false. I actually, want it to print false and set the test variable to 1.

Anyone know how?

Comment: This doesn't look like C#

Comment: The confusion in calling it C# is probably that there is a C# project using RDLC files, which uses VB.NET syntax within the report file bc SSRS uses VB.NET syntax.